# Query is Running Longer. Optimize suggestion

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Table Definition and Index are like below

```
CREATE TABLE `asin` (
  `ASIN` tinytext,
  `URL` tinytext,
  KEY `ind1` (`ASIN`(20))
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT 

CREATE TABLE `info` (
  `ASIN` tinytext,
  `Title` tinytext,
  `Description` tinytext,
  KEY `ind1` (`ASIN`(20)),
  KEY `ASIN` (`ASIN`(20))
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT
```

Currently 1st table contains 15056 records and 2nd table contains 19975 records.

I want to find out the record present in asin table and not exist in info table

```
SELECT A.ASIN FROM ASIN A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM INFO B WHERE A.ASIN = B.ASIN )
```

Query took 145.2200 sec

I thought this is a efficient way query will work, but query is taking more time. Any suggestion.  I hope i provide all the details.

Comment: This article will help http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

> *"I have already tried that option, but no improvement its taking more than current time."*

I think that's you are using 20 byte prefix index on `ASIN`

**Design consideration**

1. `TINYTEXT` is evalent to `VARCHAR(255)`. There is no reason to 20 bytes prefix INDEX unless you are concerning disk space.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `asin` (
     `ASIN` VARCHAR(255),
     `URL` VARCHAR(255),
     KEY `ind1` (`ASIN`)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT;

   CREATE TABLE `info` (
     `ASIN` VARCHAR(255),
     `Title` VARCHAR(255),
     `Description` VARCHAR(255),
     KEY `ind1` (`ASIN`)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT;
   ```
2. relationship between `asin` and `info`. one-to-one? one-to-many?, If one-to-one. merge two tables into one table.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `asin` (
     `ASIN` VARCHAR(255),
     `URL` VARCHAR(255),
     `Title` VARCHAR(255),
     `Description` tinytext,
     KEY `ind1` (`ASIN`)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT;
   ```
3. you need Primary KEY

   - Not performance related with MyISAM. But Having PK is good practice.
4. use InnoDB rather than MyISAM

   - You can use FK.
   - Row level lock
   - Transaction
   - Clustered INDEX (only applicable PK)

Comment: There is no reason to 20 bytes prefix INDEX unless you are concerning disk space.There is no reason to 20 bytes prefix INDEX unless you are concerning disk space.                                                              And Regarding your VARCHAR suggestion was amazing. After declaring the table and loaded the same data, the query ran in Fraction of Second.   Thanks a Lot

Comment: @user3117500 My pleasure ;-) Finally why don't you execute Eugen's `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` query. I guess that is a little bit faster than `NOT EXISTS`. I wonder if you test both yours and Eugen's and let me know the results? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, after changing to Varchar that is better.  I tested his query with TINYTEXT declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Use a reverse left join!

```
SELECT a.asin
FROM asin AS a
LEFT JOIN info AS b ON a.ASIN=b.ASIN
WHERE b.ASIN IS NULL
```

Comment: I have already tried that option,  but no improvement its taking more than current time.  Its taking  228.010 Sec

Comment: Yes, after changing to Varchar this is running faster.  But in Tinytext it is not executing fast.

Comment: Tinytext is not able to use a join index - VARCHAR is. This makes a huge difference.